# Fruit machine game

Tags: java, game, swing

I'm a beginner in Java, and this is the first time I have written a program from scratch without a guide explaining how and where to create classes etc. Please  review my code to see whether the program has been written in a logical way.

The program is a very basic FruitMachine. The user clicks on "spin", and three cards are drawn. Depending on what these 3 cards are the user either wins or loses points. The game continues until a certain threshold is met.

**FruitMachine Class** - Main class, creates a UserInterFaceFrame

```
    public class FruitMachine {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        UserInterfaceFrame userInterface = new UserInterfaceFrame("Fruitmachine");
    }

}
```

**GameLogic class** - Controls the functioning of the game

```
import java.beans.PropertyChangeSupport;
import java.util.Random;

public class GameLogic {

private String[] cards;
private String[] drawnCards;
private int balance;


public GameLogic() {
    cards = new String[]{"Ace", "King", "Queen", "Jack", "Joker"};
    drawnCards = new String[3];
    this.balance = 100;
}

public String[] getCards() {
    return cards;
}

public int getBalance() {
    return balance;
}

public String getDrawnCardAtX(int x) {
    return drawnCards[x];
}

public void setBalance(int newBalance) {
    balance = newBalance;
}

public String spin() {

    Random random = new Random();
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {

        drawnCards[i] = cards[random.nextInt(cards.length)];
        System.out.println(drawnCards[i]);

        if (drawnCards[i].equals("Joker")) {
            balance -= 25;
            count++;
        }
    }
    if (count > 1) {
        return count + " jokers: you lose " + (25 * count) + " points";
    }
    if (count != 0) {
        return count + " joker: you lose " + (25 * count) + " points";
    }

    if (drawnCards[0].equals(drawnCards[1]) && drawnCards[1].equals(drawnCards[2])) {
        balance += 50;
        return "Three of a kind - you win 50 points";

    } else if (drawnCards[0].equals(drawnCards[1]) || drawnCards[0].equals(drawnCards[2])
            || drawnCards[1].equals(drawnCards[2])) {

        balance += 20;
        return "Two of a kind - you win 20 points";
    }
    return null;
}
}
```

**UserInterFace class** - Creates a JFrame and fills it with JPanels for the user interface.

```
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeListener;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;

public class UserInterfaceFrame extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
private GameLogic gamelogic;

;

public UserInterfaceFrame(String title) {
    super(title);
    setSize(600, 400);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setVisible(true);
    setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 0));

    this.gamelogic = new GameLogic();

    JPanel labelsBorder = new JPanel();
    labelsBorder.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLoweredBevelBorder());
    JPanel labels = new JPanel();
    labels.setLayout(new BoxLayout(labels, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

    DataLabel balanceLabel = new DataLabel("Balance is " + gamelogic.getBalance());
    labels.add(balanceLabel);

    DataLabel cards = new DataLabel("Welcome");
    labels.add(cards);

    DataLabel winLose = new DataLabel("");
    labels.add(winLose);

    labelsBorder.add(labels);

    JPanel lowerFrame = new JPanel();
    lowerFrame.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 2));

    JPanel lowerRightFrame = new JPanel();
    lowerRightFrame.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 0));
    lowerRightFrame.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(60, 60, 60, 60));

    JPanel lowerLeftFrame = new JPanel();
    lowerLeftFrame.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 3, 30, 0));
    lowerLeftFrame.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(50, 50, 50, 50));
    JPanel card1 = new CardPanel();
    JLabel card1Label = new JLabel("", SwingConstants.CENTER);
    card1.add(card1Label);

    JPanel card2 = new CardPanel();
    JLabel card2Label = new JLabel("", SwingConstants.CENTER);
    card2.add(card2Label);

    JPanel card3 = new CardPanel();
    JLabel card3Label = new JLabel("", SwingConstants.CENTER);
    card3.add(card3Label);

    lowerLeftFrame.add(card1);
    lowerLeftFrame.add(card2);
    lowerLeftFrame.add(card3);

    JButton spin = new JButton("Spin");
    spin.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            cards.setText(gamelogic.spin());
            balanceLabel.setText("Balance is " + gamelogic.getBalance());
            card1Label.setText(gamelogic.getDrawnCardAtX(0));
            card2Label.setText(gamelogic.getDrawnCardAtX(1));
            card3Label.setText(gamelogic.getDrawnCardAtX(2));

        }
    });

    JButton reset = new JButton("New game");
    reset.setEnabled(false);
    reset.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            gamelogic.setBalance(100);
            reset.setEnabled(false);
            spin.setEnabled(true);
            winLose.setText("");
            balanceLabel.setText("Balance is: " + gamelogic.getBalance());

        }
    });

    balanceLabel.addPropertyChangeListener(new PropertyChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent event) {
            if (gamelogic.getBalance() < 0) {
                winLose.setText("You lose!");
                reset.setEnabled(true);
                spin.setEnabled(false);
            }
            if (gamelogic.getBalance() > 150) {
                winLose.setText("You win!");
                reset.setEnabled(true);
                spin.setEnabled(false);
            }
        }
    });

    lowerRightFrame.add(spin);
    lowerRightFrame.add(reset);

    lowerFrame.add(lowerLeftFrame);
    lowerFrame.add(lowerRightFrame);

    add(labelsBorder);
    add(lowerFrame);

    setVisible(true);
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

}
```

**DataLabel Class** - Extends JPanel to overwrite some of the default behaviour

```
    import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class DataLabel extends JLabel {

    public DataLabel(String setString) {
        super(setString);
        setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(20, 20, 20, 20));
    }

}
```

**Card Panel Class**

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class CardPanel extends JPanel {

    public CardPanel() {
        setBorder(BorderFactory.createRaisedBevelBorder()); // Creates a raised border around the edge of the cards to make them "pop".
        setBackground(Color.yellow); // Sets the colour of the cards to yellow
        setLayout(new GridBagLayout()); // GridBagLayout with out any constraints will always centre a JLabel.
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello sepalous, could you maybe explain in more detail what your code does?

Comment: Please [edit] your post and make the title describe/summarize the purpose of the code, and take a few minutes to better describe the components and their purpose. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

**'Card' could be an ENUM.**
This should also be a static final class variable, for example:

```
private static final Card[] CARDS = new Card[]{Card.ACE, Card.KING, Card.QUEEN, Card.JACK, Card.JOKER};
```

**Avoid magic numbers**, the '3' here should be declared, same for the starting balance

```
private static final int NUMBER_OF_CARDS_DRAWN = 3;
private static final int STARTING_BALANCE = 100;
```

Here you use the magic number '3' again, which should be changed to variable

```
// Changed '3' to 'NUMBER_OF_CARDS_DRAWN'
drawnCards = new String[NUMBER_OF_CARDS_DRAWN];
...
for (int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_CARDS_DRAWN; i++) {
```

This does not make sense. Count is never decremented so the second if statement will never be reached. You can remove it.

```
if (count > 1) {
    return count + " jokers: you lose " + (25 * count) + " points";
}
// You can remove this.
if (count != 0) {
    return count + " joker: you lose " + (25 * count) + " points";
}
```

Remove magic numbers '25, '50', '20'. **Use static variables**

**Avoid having game logic inside your UI.**

The number of cards should be retrieved from the GameLogic, then add that number of cards.

```
// Needs to be refactored into a for-loop, given the NumberOfCards is a variable.
lowerLeftFrame.add(card1);
lowerLeftFrame.add(card2);
lowerLeftFrame.add(card3);
```

Same here, if you have an  ArrayList of labels, you'll need to refactor this into a for-loop.

```
// Needs to be refactored into a for-loop, given the NumberOfCards is a variable.
card1Label.setText(gamelogic.getDrawnCardAtX(0));
card2Label.setText(gamelogic.getDrawnCardAtX(1));
card3Label.setText(gamelogic.getDrawnCardAtX(2));
```

This should not be in the UI. It's definetly GameLogic. Consider moving to constructor of GameLogic

```
// Doesn't belong in UI. Consider putting it in the constructor of GameLogic
gamelogic.setBalance(100);
reset.setEnabled(false);
spin.setEnabled(true);
```

This is very much GameLogic and does not belong in the UI

```
// This is very much GameLogic, doesn't belong in UI
if (gamelogic.getBalance() < 0) {
    winLose.setText("You lose!");
    reset.setEnabled(true);
    spin.setEnabled(false);
}
if (gamelogic.getBalance() > 150) {
    winLose.setText("You win!");
    reset.setEnabled(true);
    spin.setEnabled(false);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's show how to split the model up and remove all the UI elements.

First of all, we want to play a card game, so let's define the cards:

```
public enum Card {
    ACE, KING, QUEEN, JACK, JOKER;
}
```

---

We have some kind of account with points:

```
import java.util.function.Predicate;

public final class Account {
    private int balance;

    public Account(int startingBalance) {
        this.balance = startingBalance;
    }

    public int getBalance() {
        return balance;
    }

    public void withdraw(int loss) {
        balance -= loss;
    }

    public void deposit(int gain) {
        balance += gain;
    }

    public boolean test(Predicate<Integer> test) {
        return test.test(balance);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("Account has %d points", balance);
    }
}
```

So that god rid of that part of the equations, we don't want anything in the machine description itself if we can separate it out. Note that we don't supply a "setter".

---

Now we have multiple things resulting from a single spin. Somehow we must present them in the GUI, but without directly calling the GUI. Tricky? Not that tricky, just use a *listener* interface that the GUI classes can implement:

```
import java.util.List;

public interface SpinListener {
    void showCardSpin(List<Card> cards);
    void showResult(String result);
}
```

---

Fine, now let's implement the game:

```
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.EnumSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;

public final class FruityMacFruitMachine {
    // in the end just a list of all the cards as an unmodifiable constant value
    private final static List<Card> CARDS =
            Collections.unmodifiableList(new ArrayList<Card>(EnumSet.allOf(Card.class)));
    private static final int CARD_COUNT = 3;

    private static final int LOSS_PER_JOKER = 25;
    private static final int WINNINGS_FOR_THREE_OF_A_KIND = 50;
    private static final int WINNINGS_FOR_TWO_OF_A_KIND = 20;

    // I'm a security buff, secure randoms are *more* random than Random
    private final Random random = new SecureRandom();
    private final Account account;
    private SpinListener listener;

    // we create the machine with an account and a listener for the results
    public FruityMacFruitMachine(Account account, SpinListener listener) {
        this.account = account;
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    // create a card spin, clearly a separate method
    private List<Card> cardSpin(int amountOfCards) {
        List<Card> drawnCards = new ArrayList<Card>(amountOfCards);
        for (int i = 0; i < amountOfCards; i++) {
            drawnCards.add(CARDS.get(random.nextInt(CARDS.size())));
        }
        return drawnCards;
    }

    // the spin and all the followup moves
    public void spin() {
        // take a spin
        List<Card> draw = cardSpin(CARD_COUNT);
        // the GUI should not change the draw, right?
        listener.showCardSpin(Collections.unmodifiableList(draw));

        // check for jokers by iterating over the cards,
        // filtering out the jokers and then counting them
        int jokers = (int) draw.stream().filter(card -> card == Card.JOKER).count();
        if (jokers >= 1) {
            // we reuse the loss, no need to calculate twice!
            int loss = LOSS_PER_JOKER * jokers;
            account.withdraw(loss);
            listener.showResult(String.format("%d joker(s): you lose %d points", jokers, loss));
            return;
        }

        // we now count the distinct cards
        int distinctCards = (int) draw.stream().distinct().count();

        // all cards are distinct -> no luck
        if (distinctCards == CARD_COUNT) {
            listener.showResult("No luck, draw again");
            return;
        }

        // we just declare the variables in advance
        // and then initialize them in the if / else code blocks
        int gain;
        String result;
        if (distinctCards == 1) {
            gain = WINNINGS_FOR_THREE_OF_A_KIND;
            result = "Three of a kind";
        } else if (distinctCards == 2) {
            gain = WINNINGS_FOR_TWO_OF_A_KIND;
            result = "Two of a kind";
        } else {
            throw new IllegalStateException();
        }
        account.deposit(gain);
        listener.showResult(String.format("%s: you win %d points", result, gain));
    }
}
```

---

Now here is a console implementation of the game:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Account account = new Account(100);
    FruityMacFruitMachine game = new FruityMacFruitMachine(account, new SpinListener() {
        @Override
        public void showCardSpin(List<Card> cards) {
            System.out.println(cards);
        }

        @Override
        public void showResult(String result) {
            System.out.println(result);
        }
    });
    while (account.test(x -> x >= 50 && x < 200)) {
        game.spin();
        System.out.println(account);
        System.out.println();
    }
    System.out.println("Thank you for playing, come again");
}
```

Up to you go create a GUI around it by implementing the listener and some model / view for the `Account`.